# Mock objects with no setter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I'm using a third party library **UserContext** that only has bunch of {get;}

```
public static UserContext Current { get; }
public UserContact CurrentContact { get; }
public string UserContactName { get; }
```

In my code it's simply returning CurrentUser like so:

```
void DoSomething(){
    UserContext Current = UserContext.Current; // 3rd party lib
}
```

I have no way to set a new fake object for Unit testing. So, to in order to mock this in my code I did the following:

Created a subclass that inherits from UserContext and overwrite Current property:

```
public class UserContextFake : UserContext
{
    public new UserContext Current { get; set; }
}
```

Then created an interface and a wrapper:

```
public class UserContextWrapper : IUserContext
{
    public UserContextWrapper()
    {
        userContext = UserContext.Current;
    }

    public UserContextWrapper(UserContext context)
    {
        userContext = context;
    }

    private readonly UserContext userContext;

    public UserContext Current
    {
        get { return userContext; }
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to incject userContextWrapper into my classes. I expose two constructors: one that uses UserContext.Current (3rd party library) session stuff for production code, and constructor that can receive custom UserContextFake. In IoC I'm mapping IUserContext to UserContext

**Question**: How do I mock CurrentContact if it's not in the interface but a property of UserContext (UserContext.CurrentContact)

Comment: what do you mean correct? does it work for you?

Comment: Is this IUserContext implemented by third party library ?

Comment: it's not. That's why I had to create a wrapper and then change the code in  class that was calling UserContext.Current, to have IUserContext injected. And in the wrapper parameter less constructor will simply set private userContext to the session stuff from 3rd party lib

Comment: I think you should add everything to IUsercontext from 3rd party library which you use. You should add IUserContact to IUserContext and implement adapter for IUserContact also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just create an interface for the whole 3dr party library? Then implement this interface and use this class as wrapper for the 3rd party lib. methods. In the class under test then add e.g. property which can be used to inject the mock of the interface. Example (untested). HTH

```
public interface IThirdPartyLibraryWrapper
{
    UserContext Current { get; }
    UserContact CurrentContact { get; }
    string UserContactName { get; }
}

public class ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper 
    : IThirdPartyLibraryWrapper
{
    public UserContext Current 
    { 
        get { /* return Current from third party library */}
    }

    public UserContact CurrentContact 
    { 
        get{ /* return CurrentContact from third party library */} 
    }

    public string UserContactName 
    { 
        get{ /* return UserContactName from third party library */} 
    }
}

public class ClassUnderTest
{
    // Inject 3rd party lib
    private IThirdPartyLibraryWrapper _library;
    public virtual IThirdPartyLibraryWrapper Library
    {
        get
        {
            if (_library == null)
                _library = new ThirdPartyLibraryWrapper();
            return _library;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                _library = value;
        }
    }

    void DoSomething(){
        UserContext Current = Library.Current; 
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void DoSomething_WhenCalled_UsesLibraryMock()
{
    // Arrange
    UserContext fakeUserContext = new UserContext();
    Mock<IThirdPartyLibraryWrapper> libraryMock = new Mock<IThirdPartyLibraryWrapper>();
    libraryMock.Setup(l => l.Current).Returns(fakeUserContext);
    ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest();
    cut.Library = libraryMock.Object;

    // Act
    cut.DoSomething()

    // Assert
    // ...
}
```